# Why Does Adding A Service Reference Cause Microsoft.Owin.Security Reference Error?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have created a WCF web service.  Nowhere in that web service does it use an Owin component, as far as I can tell.  I did a solution search for the word Owin and it's not there.  When I add a service reference to my ASP.NET website it gives the compile error:

> Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

I don't want all of the Owin dlls in my project.  It just starts giving me more compile errors.  How can I get out of Owin hell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the solution to get Owin out of my service reference.  When I click Add Service Reference, on the dialog box I click Advanced... and on the second dialog box I uncheck Reuse types in referenced assemblies.  Then the project would compile with no Owin references.